# Linked List Only Showing Last Value Entered

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to become a little more adept with linked lists. I've watched several videos and read multiple forum posts, but I am still having issues. I am trying to start with a simple linked list.  However, with my current code only the last value prints. I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me what I have done wrong. Also, I usually define all my functions in the main.cpp file. However, it would not let me do this for my linked list. Also, is defining all functions in the main.cpp file a good practice or a habit I should break?

Thanks in advance :).
Below is my linkedlist file:

```
  #pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
    struct node {
        int data;
        node *next;

    };
public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = NULL;
    }

    node *newNode;
    node *temp;
    node *head;

    void insertData(int value) {
        newNode = new node;
        newNode->data = value;
        temp = newNode;
        head = newNode;
        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = temp->next;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }

    void printList() {
        node *print;
        print = head;
        while (print != NULL) {
        cout << print->data;
        print = print->next;
        }
    }

};
```

Here is my main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    LinkedList list;
    list.insertData(1);
    list.insertData(2);
    list.insertData(3);
    list.printList();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to insert a node: make a new node, set its next pointer to the current head, set the current head to the new node. It's that simple. What is going on with all the assignments in `insertData`?

Comment: I watched a video on linked lists and the guy in the video kept saying to use a temporary pointer to link the list together. He had a pointer for a new node, a pointer for the head, and a temporary pointer. It is still not displaying correctly. Does my print function look correct?

Comment: He probably meant `node* temp = new node; temp->data = value; temp->next = head; head = temp;`

Comment: I probably misinterpreted what he was saying -- I am fairly new to this after all. It works now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void insertData(int value) {
    newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = value;
    temp = newNode;
    head = newNode;
    temp->next = newNode;
    temp = temp->next;
    newNode->next = NULL;
}
```

In your code, `head = newNode` takes whatever `head` was pointing to, and throws it out in favor of `newNode`. Essentially, every time you try to insert a new value into the list, you discard the whole list.

Rather, your insert should do something like

```
void insertData(int value) {
    newNode = new node; //Create ourselves a new node
    newNode->data = value; //Put the proper value in
    newNode->next = head; //Make it so the whole list is after our node
    head = newNode; //Make our node the first in the list
}
```

There are some other things in your code I would advise changing, like the fact that you have `newNode` and `temp` as member variables when they could simply be local to the functions, and your lack of a destructor. But your print function should work with the modified insert (see it run [here](http://ideone.com/2S5Eeu)).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. It is much clearer to me now. Looks like I was trying to complicate things a bit, haha :).  Also, thanks for the advice on the local variables and destructor. I will definitely take those things into account for now on.